# The following setups were not matched - converting JustMock to Moq

Tags: tdd, moq, justmock

I am going through this tutorial http://blogs.telerik.com/justteam/posts/13-10-25/30-days-of-tdd-day-17-specifying-order-of-execution-in-mocks in regards to TDD. I am attempting to adapt a JustMock statement to Moq.

```
enter code here [Test]
    public void testname()
    {
        var customerId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var customerToReturn = new Customer { Id = customerId};

        //JustCode
        Mock _customerService = Mock.Create<ICustomerService>();
        Mock.Arrange(() => _customerService.GetCustomer(customerId)).Returns(customer).OccursOnce();


        //Moq
        Mock<ICustomerService> _customerService = new Mock <ICustomerService>();
        _customerService.Setup(os => os.GetCustomer(customerId)).Returns(customerToReturn);
        _customerService.VerifyAll();
    }
```

When the test is ran, I get this exception:

```
Moq.MockVerificationException : The following setups were not matched:ICustomerService os => os.GetCustomer(a1a0d25c-e14a-4c68-ade9-bc3d7dd5c2bc)
```

When I change .VerifyAll() to .Verify(), the test passes, but I am uncertain if this is correct.

**Question**: What is the proper way to adapt this code? Is .VerifyAll() not similiar to .OccursOnce()?

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for the two examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing the .verifiable on the setup.  Also you can avoid any verifiable , just use the mock.Verify at the end. You must also call the mocked instance so the verifable work.
https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Please see 2 approaches below.

```
    [Test]
    public void testname()
    {
        var customerId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var customerToReturn = new Customer { Id = customerId};

        //Moq
        var _customerService = new Mock <ICustomerService>();
        _customerService.Setup(os => os.GetCustomer(customerId)).Returns(customerToReturn).Verifiable();

        var cust = _customerService.Object.GetCustomer(customerId);

        _customerService.VerifyAll();
    }


    [Test]
    public void testname1()
    {
        var customerId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var customerToReturn = new Customer { Id = customerId };

        //Moq
        var _customerService = new Mock<ICustomerService>();
        _customerService.Setup(os => os.GetCustomer(customerId)).Returns(customerToReturn);

        var cust = _customerService.Object.GetCustomer(customerId);

        _customerService.Verify(x => x.GetCustomer(customerId));
    }
```

Comment: I am a little confused. In the second test, do the setup and verify use the duplicate calling code `GetCustomer(customerId)`?